web3py: How to encode tuple arguments for contract call
I am trying to call a contract function that takes argument as a tuple. I am not sure how to encode the values to form the tuple. Specifically, the integers are different types (uint24, uint256...) there should be a way for me to specifiy that:
This is the contract interface:

interface IV3SwapRouter is IUniswapV3SwapCallback {
    struct ExactInputSingleParams {
        address tokenIn;
        address tokenOut;
        uint24 fee;
        address recipient;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
    }

    /// @notice Swaps `amountIn` of one token for as much as possible of another token
    /// @dev Setting `amountIn` to 0 will cause the contract to look up its own balance,
    /// and swap the entire amount, enabling contracts to send tokens before calling this function.
    /// @param params The parameters necessary for the swap, encoded as `ExactInputSingleParams` in calldata
    /// @return amountOut The amount of the received token
    function exactInputSingle(ExactInputSingleParams calldata params) external payable returns (uint256 amountOut);

And this is my python code:
 dict_payload = {
            "tokenIn": WBNB_ADDRESS,
            "tokenOut": token_to_buy,
            "fee": fee,
            "recipient": recipient,
            "deadline": _deadline(),
            "amountIn": qty,
            "amountOutMinimum": 0,
            "sqrtPriceLimitX96": 0,
        }

        return contract.functions.exactInputSingle(
          /* WHAT TO DO HERE */
        )

I tried passing tuple(dict_payload.values()) but obviuosly it doesnt work. It wouldn't be possible for the library to know how to encode each integer (they are differnt size). What is the correct way to do that call?
